# R dplyr: Problem converting a column from character to integer using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having a problem with the following script. When converting the **min** and **max** columns of the data.frame **base** to *character*, using *dplyr*, it "converts" back to *character*. Where the result that should be **582**, ends up becoming **513**.

```r
base%>%
  mutate(ocor=str_count(pass,letter))%>%
  filter(ocor%>%between(min,max))%>%
  count()
```

To correct the problem, I tried to convert the variables into the mechanics of dplyr. However, he seems to convert back.

```r
base%>%   
  mutate(ocor=str_count(pass,letter))%>%   
  mutate(across(.cols = c('min', 'max'), .fns = ~ as.numeric(.)))%>%   
  filter(ocor%>%between(min,max))%>%   
  count() 
class(base$max) 
class(base$min)

    n
1 513
> class(base$max) 
[1] "character"
> class(base$min)
[1] "character"
```

Not using dplyr I got the correct result, an example:

```r
a<-base%>%
  mutate(ocor=str_count(pass,letter))%>%
  select(ocor)
class(base$max)
class(base$min)
base$max<-as.integer(base$max)
base$min<-as.integer(base$min)
sum(a >= base$min & a <= base$max)

[1] 582
```

I can't understand what's going on. An example of the database for clarification:

```r
head(base)

  min max letter                 pass ocor
1   2   6      c     fcpwjqhcgtffzlbj    2
2   6   9      x            xxxtwlxxx    6
3   7  10      q        nfbrgwqlvljgq    2
4   2   3      g                gjggg    4
5   2   6      s              sjsssss    6
6   4  13      b mdbctbzgcpdjbhsdctrd    3
```

The Original `Base`without changes:

```
 > head(base)
    V1 V2               V3
1  2-6 c: fcpwjqhcgtffzlbj
2  6-9 x:        xxxtwlxxx
3  5-6 w:        wwwwlwwwh
4 7-10 q:    nfbrgwqlvljgq
5  2-3 g:            gjggg
6 9-11 q:      qqqqqqnqgqq
```

The changes:

```
base<-read.table('base.txt')
library(tidyverse)
base<-base%>%
  separate(V1,c('min','max'),'-')%>%
  rename(letter=V2,pass=V3)%>%
  mutate(letter = str_replace(letter,':',''))
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data (post the output of `dput(base)`), thanks!

Comment: For sure! I put the edition and a link to upload the txt [link](https://textuploader.com/1e3u2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are not altering `base`.

`%>%` does not assign the result to a variable. I.e.

```
base %>% mutate(foo=bar(x))
```

does not alter `base`. It will just show the result on the console (and none if you are running the script or calling it from a function).

You might be confusing the pipe-operator with %<>% (found in the package magrittr) which uses the left-hand variable as input for the pipe, and overwrites the variable with the modified result.

Try

```
base <- base%>%   
  mutate(ocor=str_count(pass,letter))%>%   
  mutate(across(.cols = c('min', 'max'), .fns = ~ as.numeric(.)))%>%   
  filter(ocor%>%between(min,max))%>%   
  count()
```

Re. the issue with `min` and `max` being converted back to characters, I cannot reproduce.

Re. the issue with filtering not working as expected, it that `between` doesn't seem to care for vectors for inputs `left` and `right`. A fairly new thing is the use of `rowwise`:

Without `rowwise`:

```
base%>%   
    mutate(ocor=str_count(pass,letter))%>%   
    mutate(across(.cols = c('min', 'max'), .fns = ~ as.numeric(.)))%>%   
    mutate(between(ocor, min,max))
  min max letter                 pass ocor between(ocor, min, max)
1   2   6      c     fcpwjqhcgtffzlbj    2                    TRUE
2   6   9      x            xxxtwlxxx    6                    TRUE
3   7  10      q        nfbrgwqlvljgq    2                    TRUE
4   2   3      g                gjggg    4                    TRUE
5   2   6      s              sjsssss    6                    TRUE
6   4  13      b mdbctbzgcpdjbhsdctrd    3                    TRUE
```

With `rowwise`:

```
base%>%   
    mutate(ocor=str_count(pass,letter))%>%   
    mutate(across(.cols = c('min', 'max'), .fns = ~ as.numeric(.)))%>%   
    rowwise %>% mutate(between(ocor, min,max))
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Rowwise: 
    min   max letter pass                  ocor `between(ocor, min, max)`
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>                <int> <lgl>                    
1     2     6 c      fcpwjqhcgtffzlbj         2 TRUE                     
2     6     9 x      xxxtwlxxx                6 TRUE                     
3     7    10 q      nfbrgwqlvljgq            2 FALSE                    
4     2     3 g      gjggg                    4 FALSE                    
5     2     6 s      sjsssss                  6 TRUE                     
6     4    13 b      mdbctbzgcpdjbhsdctrd     3 FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for listening. However, unfortunately I continue with the same result(*513*). I really don't understand.

Comment: Using `%<>%` I also get the same result, the problem continue. @MrGumble

Comment: Great! With `rowwise` I can get the right result. Thank you very much for your great help! I didn't know this function, thanks.

Comment: Too bad I didn't discover the "converted back to characters" problem